# Django InMemoryUploadedFile object has not attribute reader

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to upload a csv file to insert into the model I created since the data in the csv is quite a lot I cannot manually input it all. I've watched a tutorial and I kinda copy pasted every detail the tutorial gave, the problem is when I'm click the upload button, an attributeerror appears at this line of the views.py

```
for col in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|"):
```

Im using python 3.8
Django 3.1

Models.py

```
class Dev(models.Model):         
    projName = models.CharField(max_length=255)         
    clientName = models.CharField(max_length=255)         
    projDesc = models.CharField(max_length=255)        
    projTask = models.CharField(max_length=255)         
    userName = models.CharField(max_length=255)         
    userEmail = models.CharField(max_length=255)         
    projTag = models.CharField(max_length=255)         
    billable = models.BooleanField()         
    dateStart = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)         
    timeStart = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)         
    dateEnd = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)         
    timeEnd = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)         
    timeDuration = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)         
    duration = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)         
    billRate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)         
    billAmount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

and here is the views.py

```
 from django.shortcuts import render 
 from django.http import HttpResponse import csv, io 
 from django.contrib import messages 
 from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required 
 from .models import Dev  

# Create your views here. 
def homepage(request):   
    return render(request, 'Home.html')       

@permission_required('admin.can_add_log_entry') 
def csv_upload(request):   
    template = "upload.html"      
    prompt = {       'order': 'Order of the CSV chuchu'   
    }      
    if request.method == "GET":     
        return render(request, template, prompt)        

    csv = request.FILES['file']      
    if not csv.name.endswith('.csv'):     
        message.error(request, 'Not a csv file, please choose another file.') 
       
    data_set = csv.read().decode('UTF-8')   
    io_string = io.StringIO(data_set)   
    next(io_string)   
    for col in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|"):     
    _, created = Dev.objects.update_or_create(        
        projName = column[0],        
    `       clientName = column[1],        
        projDesc = column[2],        
        projTask = column[3],        
        userName = column[4],        
        userEmail = column[5],        
        projTag = column[6],        
        billable = column[7],        
        dateStart = column[8],        
        timeStart = column[9],        
        dateEnd = column[10],        
        timeEnd = column[11],        
        timeDuration = column[12],        
        duration = column[13],        
        billRate = column[14],        
        billAmount = column[15]     
    )
```

the html file

```
{% if messages %}     
    {% for message in messages %}       
        <div>         
            {{message|safe}}       
        </div>     
    {% endfor %} 
{% else %} 
    {{order}} 
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="homepage"></form>     
        {% csrf_token %}     
        <label>Upload</label>     
        <input type="file" name="file">     
        <button type="submit">Upload</button> 
    </form> 
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Your form action is `homepage`. I guess that would simply reload the homepage when the form is submitted _in most cases_.

Comment: I just recently added that to somewhat show me whether the button works or not. And still nothing happens when I click upload

Comment: You just said it will reload the homepage. that also doesn't happen. (homepage is a different html file)

Comment: That's because you immediately closed the `form` tag after opening it.

Comment: ow.......kayy....

Comment: Now it returns an error "InMemoryUPloadedFile" object has no attribute reader and it returns the line 32 for the views.py

Comment: This is a different issue. You may submit that as a new question.